# How to get a thread count for running process in Win8?

Tags: windows-8, task-manager, threads

How do I display the column that lists the thread count for the running process in the task manager in Win8? The View menu doesn't seem to have any option that would allow to add nor does right clicking on the column header. If this feature is not available in Win8 (why MS?), what are the alternatives?

I did come across the same question for Win7, but the solution to that question is not applicable in win8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been a while since I was on Win8 so bear with me, but the Win10 taskmgr is pretty much the same so I am pretty confident this is the answer you are after.

The column you are looking for is no longer on the "Processes" tab of the Task Manager window like you are used to.  You now have to go to the Details tab, right click in the column headers, and choose "Select columns" from the dropdown menu. From there you would put a checkmark in the Threads row to see the threads in the Details grid.

Comment: works on my Win 8. +1 One of my Chrome processes has 44 threads!